# PlatformBuilder: INCLUDE path name with spaces

Tags: windows-ce, platform-builder

I've inherited a PlatformBuilder subproject that needs the ATLMFC includes.  It was installed at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include`  When trying to include this (in the sources file): `INCLUDES=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include` it gets translated to `-IC:\ProgramFiles\MicrosoftVisualStudio9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include` (Where the space are dropped at the cmdline.)  `INCLUDES="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\ce\atlmfc\include"` does not work.  (syntax error)

I've tried to add the path to the system includes (Projects and Solutions: C++ Directories) but PlatformBuilder does not use these dir's during a build.

Is there a way to include a path with spaces in Platform Builder?

Answer (score 0):

Add a junction (symbolic link) to the drives root:

```
cd c:\

mklink /J myVisualStudio9 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0"
```

then use it

```
INCLUDES=C:\myVisualStudio9\VC\ce\atlmfc\include
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths with spaces are the Win CE kriptonyte. They usually generate issues and not so easy to understand error messages. A symlink or just a copy of the folder contents in a path without spaces are the only working solutions.